# Solving $\pi(128a-0.096a^3+\frac{81}{2500000}a^5)=3000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Given that
$$\pi(128a-0.096a^3+\frac{81}{2500000}a^5)=3000$$
find the value of $a$.

Not sure how to go about this algebraic equation. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: On its face this is a degree 5 polynomial, so there is no "general solution method" analogous to the quadratic formula (for degree 2). So it would help if you provide some context for this question. Is it homework? Did it come up in some research? This will help people to guess whether there is a trick to solve it, or if you just have to approximate.

Comment: A relevant link https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bring-JerrardQuinticForm.html . Good luck !

Comment: @halrankard its for a volume fo revolution question. "A manufacturer is making a small barrel with curved sides. The shape is formed by rotating a segment of the curve $y=8-0.009x^2$ about the x-axis. Given that the barrel needs to contain 3 liters of liquid, and the units are in centimeters, show that the length has to be about 15.6cm."

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no explicit solution to most quintic polynomials, you need to apply some numerical mthod.

So, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(a)=\pi\left(128a-\frac{12}{125}a^3+\frac{81}{2500000}a^5\right)-3000$$ The coefficients are so different that we can suppose that the first term is really the most dominant and a first approximation is more than likely
$$a_0=\frac{3000}{128 \pi}=\frac{375}{16 \pi }\approx 7.46039$$ Now, let $a=b+a_0$ and the equation becomes
$$-\frac{1265625 \left(32768 \pi ^2-6075\right)}{33554432 \pi
   ^4}+\left(\frac{102515625}{2097152 \pi ^3}-\frac{10125}{64 \pi }+128 \pi \right)
   b+\left(\frac{273375}{65536 \pi ^2}-\frac{27}{4}\right)
   b^2+\left(\frac{729}{4096 \pi }-\frac{12 \pi }{125}\right) b^3+\frac{243
   b^4}{64000}+\frac{81 \pi  b^5}{2500000}$$ and again the coefficients are so different that we could limit to the first and second term, that is to say
$$b_0=\frac{\frac{1265625 \left(32768 \pi ^2-6075\right)}{33554432 \pi
   ^4} } {\frac{102515625}{2097152 \pi ^3}-\frac{10125}{64 \pi }+128 \pi }=\frac{1265625 \left(32768 \pi ^2-6075\right)}{16 \pi  \left(10125-16384 \pi
   ^2\right)^2}\approx 0.347755$$ we could repeat the process using $b=c+b_0$ and get $c_0 \approx 0.0022228$. I suppose that we can now stop and  the *approximation* is then
$$a=7.46039+0.347755+0.0022228\sim 7.81037$$

As you see, nothing very difficult; by the way, this is the kinf of process which was used by Newton to invent the so-called Newton method.

Now, (be sure that you will learn it very soon, let us use Newton method and being very lazy (this is not a sin !), we shall start with $a_0=0$. The generated iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n  & a_n \\
 0 & 0.000000000 \\
 1 & 7.460387957 \\
 2 & 7.808143094 \\
 3 & 7.810365901 \\
 4 & 7.810365994
\end{array}
\right)$$